# Extend templates from outside templates directory

Tags: templating, craft3

I have a setup where I'm using a component library that I have as an npm package. To use these components I need to extend templates that live outside of the /templates directory. So I need to achieve something like:

`{% extends "../../../../node_modules/design-system/page-templates/_template.njk" %}`

I will be extended from within a template that is located from within the /templates directory but allows for extends from outside of it.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define and register your [template roots](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/template-roots.html) for this folder:

```php
Event::on(
    View::class,
    View::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_TEMPLATE_ROOTS,
    function(RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $e) {{
        $e->roots['my-fancy-prefix'] = 'someDir';
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Where would I add this?

Comment: In your default module - https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module